# Trouble with referencing C code from python using ctypes

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

I was trying to create a shared library of C language to be referenced from Python. The main problem is that I could only get the address of the return pointer to array in C. I have tried to read value from the returned address sent by C function. However, every approach I tried was causing Python failure and cannot access the value. Is there anyone could give some kind advises?

```py
path='../crypto_lib/vrf.so'

lib=CDLL(path)
sk = lib.new_sk()
print(sk)

output:292500480
```

It is the C code I want to use, which generates a secret key and return with hex type converted and stored in shexbuf. Code is not my own work, mimicing some examples on github, it works fine while compiling with C. Giving expected output

```c
char* new_sk(){

    uint8_t public_key[crypto_sign_PUBLICKEYBYTES];

    uint8_t secret_key[crypto_sign_SECRETKEYBYTES];

    static char shexbuf[2*crypto_sign_SECRETKEYBYTES+1];

    crypto_vrf_keypair(public_key, secret_key);
    char* result;
    result = to_hex(shexbuf, secret_key,  crypto_sign_SECRETKEYBYTES);
    return shexbuf;

}
```

I expected to get the value of secret key,
but I could only get something appeared to be address. 
When I tried to use ctype to read value from the address, the window of python quit unexpectedly popped up

Comment: Advice is to read the documentation for ctypes, specifically `restype`.

Comment: Hi, man. I will give it a go today, i already tried

Comment: Didn't get this far? https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#return-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ctypes` defaults to `c_int` for parameters and return value.  You're seeing the address of the returned string as a `c_int`.  Set the `.restype` appropriately:

```
lib=CDLL(path)
lib.new_sk.restype = c_char_p
sk = lib.new_sk()
print(sk)
```

Comment: Cheers, man. Problem solved, i should have read the docs more carefully.